# Python: Subsetting a list according to the attribute

Tags: python, class, attributes, subset

I have a list of instances of MC and I want to subset all the instances which attribute equals 2. Can you help me creating the function "superfunction" that does either subset according to a value to accept or to reject.

```
class MC(object):
     def __init__(self,smth):
         self.smth=smth

l = [MC(2),MC(4),MC(1),MC(2),MC(2),MC(-3),MC(0)]

def superfunction (a_list,attr,value_to_accept=None, value_to_reject=None):
     return a_subset
```

How would it work for a dictionnary ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific example, you could use a list comprehension like so:

```
return [x for x in a_list if x.smth == 2]
```

For your general example, you could do a similar thing:

```
if value_to_accept is not None:
    return [x for x in a_list if x.smth == value_to_accept]
if value_to_reject is not None:
    return [x for x in a_list if x.smth != value_to_reject]
return []
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need a separate function to do this. List comprehensions are pretty straightforward:

```
[mc from l if mc.smth == value_to_accept]
[mc from l if mc.smth != value_to_reject]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `filter()` with a predicate:

```
def superfunction (a_list, attr, value_to_accept=None, value_to_reject=None):
    def predicate(item):
        value = getattr(item, attr)
        if value_to_reject is not None and value != value_to_reject:
            return False
        if value_to_accept is not None and value == value_to_accept:
            return True
        return False

   return filter(predicate, a_list)
```

This let's you specify either a value to accept or to reject.

Usually, however, you'd use an inline list comprehension instead of a function:

```
[elem for elem in a_list if a_list.attr == value_to_accept]
```